# Python / Scrapy - code skips products, even though xpath is the same for all products listed

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy, response

Trying to scrape information from the `www.archive.org`, which contains historic product data.  My code below, tries to click on every product listed, `scrape` the information per product, and do the same for subsequent pages.

The problem is that it SKIPS some products (20 in particular), even though the xpath:

```
 products = response.xpath("//article[contains(@class,'product result-prd')]")
```

is the same for all products. Please see my complete code below.

```
class CurrysSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'currys_mobiles_2015'
    #allowed_domains = ['www.currys.co.uk']
    start_urls = ['https://web.archive.org/web/20151204170941/http://www.currys.co.uk/gbuk/phones-broadband-and-sat-nav/mobile-phones-and-accessories/mobile-phones/362_3412_32041_xx_xx/xx-criteria.html']

    def parse(self, response):
        products = response.xpath("//article[contains(@class,'product result-prd')]") # done

        for product in products:
            brand = product.xpath(".//span[@data-product='brand']/text()").get() # done
            link = product.xpath(".//div[@class='productListImage']/a/@href").get() # done
            price = product.xpath(".//strong[@class='price']/text()").get().strip() # done
            description = product.xpath(".//ul[@class='productDescription']/li/text()").getall() # done

            absolute_url = link # done
           
            yield scrapy.Request(url=absolute_url,callback=self.parse_product,
             meta={'brand_name':brand,
            'product_price':price,
            'product_description':description}) # done

        # process next page
        next_page_url = response.xpath("//ul[@class='pagination']//li[last()]//@href").get()
        absolute_next_page_url = next_page_url

        if next_page_url:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=absolute_next_page_url,callback=self.parse)


    def parse_product(self, response):
        .....
```

I have noticed this problem in many websites that I tried to scrape, and I am not sure why some products are skipped, since the `xpath` is the same for all of the product listings.

Would appreciate some feedback on this.

Answer (score 0):

try to take a look if those products are present in page html or loaded via js.
Just ctrl+U and check html body for those products.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately that is not the case, as when I search the HTML tree of the website using ```xpath```, I can find the products even after disabling for JS.

Comment: I'd suggest to use `response.css('article.product')` as it's a bit wider selector but still good for your purposes. And it's more beautiful (: and second I'd suggest you to use for example IPDB with conditions like - if no products found - go to debugger. Save page html and check manually, since your code is looking good to me.

Comment: Thanks. So do you mean to generally use ```css``` instead of ```xpath```  when web scraping? Or just on specific occasions?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible the individual pages are not loading properly possibly due to JS loading, as the rest of your code looks fine (though I would recommend using `normalize-space($xpath)` instead of `.strip()` for price).

In order to test this (on Chrome), visit your target web page, Open Chrome Dev Tools(F12), Click "Console" and Ctrl+Shift+P to pull up command window.

Next, type in "Disable Javascript" and select that option when it shows up. Now, Ctrl+R to refresh the page, and this is the "View" that your web-scraper gets. Check your Xpath expressions now.

If you do have issues, consider using [scrapy-splash](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/leaks.html) or [scrapy-selenium](https://github.com/clemfromspace/scrapy-selenium) to load this JS.

EDIT: I would check for the possibility of a memory leak. According to [scrapy docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/leaks.html), using the meta attribute in your callback will sometimes cause leaks.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. using ```normalize-space``` instead of ```strip``` is a good point. Regarding the rest of your answer, that is exactly what I do. I turn off JS and inspect the page, and use the Scrapy console to test the ```xpath``` expressions first.